# If statement for the date in a cell being greater than a number of days

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need an IF statement that will return a value to a cell if the date in another cell gets to be older than a certain number of days. For some reason I can't get the statement to recognize the date in the first cell.

I'm trying
=IF(A1>180, "Yes", "No")

The return I get is always Yes. I'm thinking it has something to do with converting the date to a number, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the second base for a comparison. more than 180 days older than *what*? right now you are checking if A1 is more than 180 days greater than 0.

If you want to compare with today or right *now*, use `=IF((NOW()-A1)>180, "Yes", "No")`.

If you additionally want it to show "Yes" for blank values, use `=IF(A1="","Yes",IF((NOW()-A1)>180, "Yes", "No"))`.

Comment: I got close so I'm assuming my question isn't phrased properly and you're closer to the answer. What I need is if A1 is blank (no date) or the date in A1 is less than 180 days from today I need the answer to be "NO" otherwise I need the answer to be "Yes".

Comment: that extra IF would then make it: `=IF(A1="","",IF((NOW()-A1)>180, "Yes", "No"))` or `=IF(AND(A1<>"",(NOW()-A1)>180), "Yes", "No")`. If you have many copies of the formula, the first one is slightly faster than the second one, probably because of the AND.

Comment: That works almost which means I'm sure I did something wrong. I'll just post the formula. =IF(A1="","",IF((NOW()-A1)<180,"Yes","No")) which is supposed to say if A1 is blank or less than 180 days then yes otherwise no. However what I'm getting is if A1 is blank the answer is blank also.

Comment: yes, I got you wrong. Adjusted.

Comment: I don't see what was adjusted. I apologize for being so ignorant.

Comment: I just saw your adjustment. Thank you!! That did it and makes total sense now that I see it.

Comment: I apologize I was out of the country. Forgive me but how do I upvote or accept?

Comment: Left of the answer text, there are arrows for up and down voting, and there's a checkmark for excepting the answer.